# attach the string element of one list to the integer element of another subsist of a list in each sub list in python

Tags: python

i m trying to add the name of the column in pandas data frame to each element in that column so i added the column names to a list as well as iterated the rows to a list . so now i need to do something like this:

```
names=['a','c']
list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
for nlist in list_of_lists:
    for element in nlist:
        print(f"{i}_{list_of_lists[element]}" for i in range( len(name)))
```

so what i need it to print is `[[a_1,c_2],[a_3,c_4]]` but this did `[[a_1,a_2],[c_3,c_4]`

Answer (score 2):

You can write a nested list comprehension that first loops over your list of lists, then zips that against the name list.

```
>>> [[f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in zip(names, sub)] for sub in list_of_lists]
[['a_1', 'c_2'], ['a_3', 'c_4']]
```

Comment: cool! perfect! how did i not think of that ? thank you so much!

Comment: @vanetoj: Remember to accept questions that helped you (green tick on the left).

Answer (score 2):

Trying to more closely match what was requested (i.e. no quotation marks):

```
class C():
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.s
    def __init__(self,c,n):
        self.s = ("%s_%d" % (c,n))
    
print( [[C(*x) for x in zip(names,lol)] for lol in list_of_lists] )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seams that there is a little mistake in your code. On the last line, name is used, but was never defined.

I wanted to ask you, is it really only to print what would be your table with the new elements' names that you wanted to do or to modify your table?

If you only want to print a str, I agree with Cory Kramer, but if what you want is to change your table, I propose this solution:

```
column_names = ['a', 'c']
columns = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

for column_counter in range(len(column_names)):
    for row_counter in range(len(columns[column_counter])):
        element = columns[column_counter][row_counter]
        # Add new element to new column
        columns[column_counter][row_counter] = str(column_names[column_counter] + '_' + str(element))
print(columns)
```

The output:

```
[['a_1', 'a_2'], ['c_3', 'c_4']]
```